# Invalid assignment in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting invalid assignment in jQuery when I am returning data from a function like this :

```
var createHtml = '';
var companyName = '';
var recName = '';
[Html,cName,recName] = abc(sugg_detail,is_last_result);


function abc(a,b,c){
return [1,2,3];
}
```

I am getting error only in Chrome. Please suggest me what I have done wrong.

Comment: Maybe not supported by Chrome. Use Babel to transpile code in ES5. `[Html,cName,recName] = abc(sugg_detail,is_last_result);`

Comment: The only browsers to natively support this ES6 syntax so far are Firefox and Safari - see the [compatibilty table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility) on MDN or [these compatibility tables](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#destructuring) (see the destructuring section)